# Accessing Apache sites on Macintosh (Snow Leopard) using internal IP address of machine

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server, ipv4

I am trying to access web sites on my Mac.

If I use `http://10.0.1.3/index.html` then I get a web page with the following error on it:  `Forbidden You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.`

If I replace the IP with 'localhost' all is good.
The URI `http://10.0.1.3/~myusername/` also works fine.

My OS firewall is disabled. There are no .htaccess files in place and my httpd.conf is pretty straightforward. I have been looking at document root permissions and ownership (apache runs as _www/_www and execute permissions are set on the document root and my index.html file in the root) but still no joy.

Here is /etc/hosts content without comment lines:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1              localhost
fe80::1%lo0      localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already checked file permissions then you are probably running into one of these directives:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

That is from the stock OS X Lion httpd.conf.  It looks like you'll need to add an allow directive somewhere if you want to hit /index.html.  I assume somewhere else in your config is an allow that lets it work if the hostname matches some virtualhost.  You'd have to post your config to help debug further.